# How to make a left panel appear on slide right gesture

Tags: javascript, css, html, zurb-foundation

I am looking for a way to make a left panel appear when I slide right on the main view of my app. I am using `Foundation` for the visual components. Other slide events are working but I could not find a way to show panel when I slide my finger right. Any hints/tips are appreciated

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23501697/2641416) may inspire you.